# Swift optional binding only allows constants

Tags: swift, swift2

Swift comes with an "optional binding" mechanism to allow for automatic unwrapping of optional value if possible. It looks okay when I first learn this, but then I found that the optional binding mechanism can only bind the unwrapped value to constants.

If I want to modify the unwrapped value, I'll have to assign it to a variable first..

```
if let regions:[String] = regionList {
    regions.removeLast() //Error!
}
```

Is there a better way to resolve this issue?

I am hoping that Apple can provide another optional binding syntax like:

```
if var regions:[String] = regionList {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if var` technique exists, but the value will only be mutable inside the `if var` scope, and it's a copy anyway because arrays are value-type.

```
var regionList:[String]? = ["a", "b"]

if var regions = regionList {
    regions.removeLast()
    regions  // ["a"]
}

regionList  // ["a", "b"]
```

To mutate your Optional array you could use optional chaining:

```
var regionList:[String]? = ["a", "b"]

regionList?.removeLast()

regionList  // ["a"]
```

The idea here is that `.removeLast()` will only be executed if `regionList?` isn't `nil`.

Comment: `regionList?.removeLast()` it a bit tricky and it is not clear to me that a future developer will easily understand the reason and the outcome. IMO being explicit is a better course to avoiding future confusion and errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually tried this `if var` syntax... but there seemed to be some problems with Xcode. If I changed my original code from `if let` to `if var`, then it'll **always** display a error message to me  as shown in the image http://imgur.com/IUDh5RM, I was stopped by this strange error...now I tried to actually compile it, it works!

Comment: @zaph I understand what you say, but Optional chaining is not tricky at all IMO. (but then I guess it's a matter of taste). Apple even has a [whole](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) page about it and how to use it.

Comment: as for your suggestion about optional chaining, it will not be suitable for my   real case. I was just simplifying it so that it'll be easier to explain my problem :)

Comment: @Jung-ShuoPai Ok, I see. No problem. :)

Comment: OK, it is not "tricky" but neither is the intent clear. One should write for the next developer who may not be as learned. IMO making intent clear trumps saving a line or so of code. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the array for nil:

```
var regionList:[String]? = ["a", "b"]

if regionList != nil {
    regionList!.removeLast() // you can safely force unwrap it here
}
```